# Bypass lookup filter for specific user

Tags: object, salesforce, lookup

Can you please let me know if there is any way to bypass lookup filter validation for specific user ?

Checkin on possibility

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

Have you actually tried anything? When defining a lookup filter you have options based on current record, the record being looked up - but also current user, their role or profile. So you can make filter "Current User: Name equals John Doe" and then define filter logic to go "(1 AND 2 AND 3) OR 4" (assuming this bypass is #4.